# filling <img src="?"> dynamically in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi would like to add img source path dynamically as shown in the snippet below, but giving error. I know img_src_path adding syntax is correct. Unfortunately I don't know the solution, need help.

Environment:

ASP.net, c#

```
    <% string a[0]="image/hello.jpg;"
  {
  String img_src_path= a[0].ToString();%>
 <li><a href='"<%#img_src_path%>"'><img src='"<%#img_src_path%>"' alt="" title=""/></a></li>
 <%}%>
```

/Shashi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your code with this:

"=" instead of "#"

the solution

```
<li><a href='"<%=img_src_path%>"'><img src='"<%=img_src_path%>"' alt="" title=""/></a></li>
```

and if you want to edit image src form code behind 
solution 2:

```
<li><a href='"<%=img_src_path%>"'><img src='"<%=img_src_path%>"' id="myImage" runat="server" alt="" title=""/></a></li>
```

edit image source form codebehind:

```
myImage.src = "imagePage";
```

Comment: This does not work, if you have runat="server" on your control.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your image tag does not have a runat="server" attribute (you will also need to add an ID in order to do this).

You also need to change your server tags like this:

FROM:

```
<%# ... %>
```

TO:

```
<%= ... %>
```

Also, the proper way to do this in ASP.Net would be to use the Image server control.

```
<asp:Image id="Image1" runat="server"></asp:Image>
```

Then, you would set the NavigateUrl property.

Answer (score 0):

The basic error we are trying to workout is **Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.**